# A subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array affecting Date conversion

Tags: arrays, crystal-reports, subscript

I have a formula that is taking an array which outputs number like this 05/28/14 and need to have it formatted as a date. I am using this code and it is telling me "A Subscript must be between 1 and the size of the array.". I think the problem is with my Month field but am unsure.

```
stringvar array dates;
numbervar d;  
numbervar m;  
numbervar y;  
dates := split({custinvd.cid-sparedate},",");  
d := val(right(dates[1],2));  
m := tonumber(dates[2]);
y := val(left(dates[3],4));  
cdate(d,m,y);
```

Comment: how many values are returned from dates?

Comment: I guess it is returning only 1 value... instead of 3 values... use `Ubound` to check number of values in an array

Comment: The real question here is what data in `{custinvd.cid-sparedate}` looks like.

Comment: The interesting thing with this set of arrays is that it returns information like so  "04/14/2014;?;?;??;?" (I was not in charge of how this field was setup and cannot change it at the moment).

From what I gather it will only ever display the first value, which is the date of this job, and the rest will always be question marks. Having since learned this I changed 

dates := split({custinvd.cid-sparedate},",");  to  dates := split({custinvd.cid-sparedate},";");  

but it still leaves me with my original issue, I almost feel like it would be necessary to do a second split after the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `{custinvd.cid-sparedate}` is always in the format "04/14/2014;?;?;??;?" then you can convert this to a date by simply stripping away the question marks and semicolon delimiters and using the `date()` function in CR:

```
date(split({custinvd.cid-sparedate},";")[1])
```

or, if you will always have leading zeros, you could even use

```
date(left({custinvd.cid-sparedate},10))
```

Comment: @Siva `cdate()` and `date()` are equivalent functions so it doesn't matter which one is used.